# Recording Normal Calls and Conference calls in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip, pbx

Set up Asterisk 13.1 on Ubuntu 16.04,Calls are Working fine as well as conference calls.However I have two Question regarding the recording of calls in asterisk.
This is the extensions.conf.

```
[default]
exten  => 1000,1,MixMonitor(${CALLERID(num)}-${STRFTIME(|EST5EDT|%m%d%Y-%H%M%S)}.gsm)
same => n,Dial(SIP/1000)
exten  => 1001,1,MixMonitor(${CALLERID(num)}-${STRFTIME(|EST5EDT|%m%d%Y-%H%M%S)}.gsm)
same => n,Dial(SIP/1001)

exten => 100,1,Answer()
exten => 100,n,Authenticate(234)
same  => n,MixMonitor(${CALLERID(num)}-${STRFTIME(|EST5EDT|%m%d%Y-%H%M%S)}.gsm)
same  => n,ConfBridge(1234)
```

And this is confbridge.conf

```
conf => 1234

[1234]
record_conference = yes
```

1)Is it necessary to define MixMonitor for every call(As I have done above for user 1000 and 1001) ,or is there a possibility where you can define it once and all calls in your asterisk server get recorded.

2)When the Conference call is recorded ,suppose if there are two users in the conf room,there are two audio files generated  instead of one,What changes do I make so theres is only one recorded audio file of the full conference?

Answer (score 0):

In asterisk it is nessesary do any action you want DO.

In your case you can use mixmonitor command in every dialplan, use pattern to do that command for large list, use external macro or gosub function and call it for calls you want be recorded.

For conference you can start enother call with mixmon(third call) using Originate or you can use internal recording.

For ANY record you can have Monitor(two files for each side of call) or mixmonitor(same, but 1st party in left channel, 2nd party in right channel, so file is single). 
So if you have 2 files, you just have non-mixed variant. Consult conference room options for mixed version.

Comment: So there's no way I could get asterisk to record a single audio file of a conference call with multiple users?